# Advanced Pawn Structure books

Tags: positional-play, pawn-structure

Hello fellow chess players. I've recently returned to the learning of this game, and as I forgot several ideas on deep mechanics, I read (again) "My System", from Nimzowitsch, and found it very useful, but I want to learn more about pawn structures and positional ideas. Would you recommend me some books? Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Welcome to stack exchange. You should avoid accepting an answer straight away as you can only accept one and it discourages others from posting their own answer if one has already been accepted. I suggest un-accepting it and giving it a day or two, as higher quality answers may be posted later

Comment: I just added an updated list of books here: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/22971/how-can-i-improve-my-knowledge-of-pawn-structure-theory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the chess youtuber with the channel that goes by the name of Hanging Pawns has a lot of good explanations about structure/openings. I downloaded a very nice book about it, but I suspect that I'm not yet on the appropriate level to concentrate on it, the book is called: Chess Structures: A Grandmaster Guide - by Mauricio Flores Rios.

Comment: That book is not free. If it is out there like that, it is an illegal copy, and thus, you should not be promoting its dissemination.

Comment: Oh, ok. I did not knew that is against the rules here.